# Programmatically add icon to the home screen

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, web-applications

I have a website and a mobile web-app for the same service.
I want to when users access the mobile site, to have a button saying "install app" that when pressed, will add the icon to the phone homescreen linking to the mobile web app.

I hope I'm clear, I don't want to make users feel like they are using a native app, from then on, avoiding making them manually add the site to the homescreen.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic code to create tiles on start:

```
// check if secondary tile is already made and pinned
ShellTile Tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("Title=SecondaryTile"));
if (Tile == null) {

// create a new secondary tile
StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();

// tile foreground data
data.Title = "Secondary tile";
data.BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Images/Blue.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
data.Count = 2;

// create a new tile for this Second Page
ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/SecondPage.xaml?Title=SecondaryTile", UriKind.Relative), data);
```

You'll need to navigate it to your desired page, then use the [WebBrowserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394020%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to go to the desired web page.

Hope that helps.